# What is the course of action to take when a question asks for upvotes?

Tags: discussion, upvotes

I edited a question today, and wound up editing this out because there were other problems with the post at the same time. But essentially there was a sort of "header-signature" at the top of this user's question:

> To anyone favouriting the question - I'm glad you find it interesting/useful. If you like it enough to favourite it, please consider upvoting it as well - it's not just to make people feel appreciated, I also need to 'spend' the reputation points the next time I set a bounty on a question. And I don't have the necessary knowledge to earn it through answering questions.

Obviously, that's not an acceptable statement to have in a question. Looking at their other questions in their profile, it does not appear at a glance that this is a pattern with this user. Should I also flag the question for moderator attention? Simply leave a comment explaining that explicitly asking for upvotes is not allowed?

Funnily enough, I think this is the first time I've come across a *question or answer post* that asks for upvotes in that post. Up until now I've only ever come across those in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, the guidance still stands: edit out, flag if rolled back.

Comment: As ironic as it looks given the latest Meta debacle, it's actually a pretty common occurence - I see it from time to time on posts.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Is it still recommended to flag in the case of rollback or is it now better to rollback the rollback for the automatic flag?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest It's always preferred to manually flag over trying to rely on the automatic flags

Comment: That is a good question - in all rollback wars I've been a part of as an active editor, it's better to flag manually before it becomes a mess for the mods to handle.

Comment: In my experience, if you roll the stubborn user's rollback, they become increasingly frustrated and lock in to their behavior quickly, so I stopped waiting for autoflags long ago. Besides, users often desist without the need to lock the post when they see their edit overruled by a mod (some are exceptionally tough, but at this point the mod is already involved and will issue a lock and/or a message to them should they persist).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Man, you are right. While there are definitely some false positives, the number of results which do actually ask for upvotes is surprisingly high (query: `is:answer please upvote`).

Comment: Yeah, @BendertheGreatest, unfortunately, upvote begging is unsurprisingly common. Although sometimes there are funny results like "please stop upvoting this" :)

Comment: I guess folks are better behaved under the tags I watch lol. Interestingly enough I'm seeing many positive hits under the [tag:javascript] and [tag:java] tags, although this is just in the UI search, I haven't written a SEDE query or anything.

Comment: Yeah, it often correlates with a tag being popular with low entry bar. Where I participate (a strict subset of TS), it's a non-issue too. Scales with size, I guess.

Comment: *"What is the course of action to take when a question asks for upvotes?"* Downvote it.

Comment: @CodyGray most such questions I have already downvoted before getting to the begging:(

Comment: @CodyGray I more meant "should I flag this for mod attention or not"? Downvoting or editing it is already a given. I probably could have used a better title but I do ask in the body whether I should flag it (which I've also gotten an answer on)